# Where can I find the Story Mode save files on PC?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I want to install a save game, but I can't find the 'Profiles' folder.

I looked in "\Documents\GTA V", but there are only two folders there: 'User music' and 'Settings'. I can't find the 'Profiles' folder, where I should put my save file. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Sounds like you were looking for existing files without having any. Easiest would be to go in the game - play till you can save, save and then go look for the existing file and replace it.

Answer (score 3):

**You can simply create the folder where you need it**, and place the files there.
To be certain, the default folder can be found at

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\Rockstar Games\GTA V\Profiles
```

The suggestion made by Иво Недев - to start a new game and see where those files are saved - ensures you have the right folder.

And for completion's sake, **in case you're playing through Steam**, the files can be found in

```
C:\ProgramData\Socialclub\<YOUR_SOCIAL_ID>\<NUMBER>
```

To ascertain yourself that you are in the right location, you can [apparently](https://steamcommunity.com/app/271590/discussions/0/611703709832294335) find the files *cfg.dat* and *pc_settings.bin* in that same folder.